# Combine Data in Tables for Same ID's.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help combining data from MySQL with PHP and showing it in the same tables.

Now I'm getting this:

```
--------------------------------------
|Order ID | Product | Quantity| Cost |
--------------------------------------
| 28      | Salad   |    4    | 10.99|
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
|Order ID | Product | Quantity| Cost |
--------------------------------------
| 28      | Pizza   |    1    | 15   |
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
|Order ID | Product | Quantity| Cost |
--------------------------------------
| 26      | Fish   |    3     | 12   |
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
|Order ID | Product | Quantity| Cost |
--------------------------------------
| 22      | Pizza   |    1     | 15  |
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
|Order ID | Product | Quantity| Cost |
--------------------------------------
| 22      | Salad   |    1    | 10.99|
--------------------------------------
```

And I want to show it like this:

```
--------------------------------------
|Order ID | Product | Quantity| Cost |
--------------------------------------
| 28      | Salad   |    4    | 10.99|
| 28      | Pizza   |    1    | 15   |
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
|Order ID | Product | Quantity| Cost |
--------------------------------------
| 26      | Fish   |    3     | 12   |
--------------------------------------

--------------------------------------
|Order ID | Product | Quantity| Cost |
--------------------------------------
| 22      | Pizza   |    1     | 15  |
| 22      | Salad   |    1    | 10.99|
--------------------------------------
```

My PHP code:

```
$username2= $_SESSION['Username'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order_detail, products WHERE order_detail.user =   '$username2' AND order_detail.productid = products.serial ORDER BY orderid DESC");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<table class='curvedEdges'>
<tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<th>Product</th>
<th>Quantity</th>
<th>Cost</th>
</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['orderid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . " LT</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

What is the easiest way to do this in PHP? Maybe someone can show me the code? :) Thanks!

Comment: Learn about how to use `JOIN`s [_random PDO/mysqli rant here_].

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$orderID = null;
$tableShown = false;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if ($orderID != $row['orderid']) {
        if ($tableShown)
            echo "</table>";

        echo "<table class='curvedEdges'>
        <tr>
        <th>Order ID</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        </tr>";
        $tableShown = true;
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['orderid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . " LT</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $orderID = $row['orderid'];
}

if ($tableShown)
    echo "</table>";
```

This should cause the HTML `table` to get recreated with headers for each change in the Order ID.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This will give him the results he's asking for.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you're echoing `</table>` in the wrong place.

Comment: Ok, that should fix it I think... Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go for two loop to achieve this -

```
    $username2= $_SESSION['Username'];
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT distinct orderid FROM order_detail, products WHERE order_detail.user =   '$username2' AND order_detail.productid = products.serial ORDER BY orderid DESC"); 

    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
    $row2orderid = $row2['orderid'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order_detail, products WHERE order_detail.user =   '$username2' AND order_detail.productid = products.serial and orderid = '$row2orderid' ORDER BY orderid DESC");

echo "<table class='curvedEdges'>
    <tr>
    <th>Order ID</th>
    <th>Product</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {    
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['orderid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . " LT</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
```